# CDI/Weld with JEE5 and Tomcat6

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, tomcat6, cdi

I'm working on a web application that is Java EE 5.  I may be able to upgrade it to EE 6 at some point, but can't at the moment.  The web app is running in Tomcat 6.  Can I use CDI with it?

I noticed in the [Weld documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/environments.html#d0e4910) that there is a note that I can't use session beans:

`There is a major limitation to using a servlet container. Weld doesn't support deploying session beans, injection using @EJB or @PersistenceContext, or using transactional events in servlet containers. For enterprise features such as these, you should really be looking at a Java EE application server.`

Does this mean I can't use the `@SessionScoped` annotation?  If so, that would be a show-stopper for using CDI at the moment.

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is about EJB session beans. You can use CDI with JSF in tomcat 6. Just follow the installation instructions for Weld.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.  Does Weld work with JSF 1.2?  The app I'd like to use this with is using EE 5.

Comment: @Jon - I don't think so. But you can deploy JSF 2.0 on tomcat 6

Comment: Apache OpenWebBeans and MyFaces CODI work with JSF 1.2 and JSF 2+